# How to check if mobile network is enabled/disabled

Tags: android

I would like to know if the mobile network is enabled or disabled.

My application is designed to help the user when he receives a phone call, and to do this I need Internet access. Thus, I would like to display an information box when the user access the application for the first time if Wi-Fi has a sleep policy and Mobile network is disabled. (I need Internet within milliseconds after the phone start ringing).

I found Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, but I can't find any information on how to check if mobile network is disabled (when Wi-Fi is on and working).

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
The problem is that I want to know if mobile network is turned of by the user (while the phone could have WiFi access at the time).

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211081/android-to-check-if-the-phone-has-a-network-provider/8211179#8211179

Comment: It's not the same. ((LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)).isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);is true when mobile network is disabled and Wi-Fi is enabled (and working). From API: location based on availability of cell tower and WiFi access points

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally found a solution. Apparently not all phones have this option:

> Home > Menu > Settings > Wireless & networks > Mobile network (checkbox)

However, for those who do, this method will work:

```
/**
 * @return null if unconfirmed
 */
public Boolean isMobileDataEnabled(){
    Object connectivityService = getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) connectivityService;

    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        return (Boolean)m.invoke(cm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @DanielNugent any ideas why?

Comment: @PeterChaula This was a security hole, it was unintentional that this was even possible in the first place.  Google fixed the security hole, so it's no longer possible to do this.  See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539445/the-setmobiledataenabled-method-is-no-longer-callable-as-of-android-l-and-later

Comment: @DanielNugent one reason why one must always avoid "hacky" reflection as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

apparently there is an alternative, more clean solution then the Reflection approach:

```
final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
final NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
int type = networkInfo.getType();
String typeName = networkInfo.getTypeName();
boolean connected = networkInfo.isConnected()
```

> networkInfo.getType() will return '0' when connected to mobile network
>   or '1' when connected trough WIFI. networkInfo.getTypeName() will return
>   the strings "mobile" or "WIFI". and networkInfo.isConnected() will tell you whether or not you have an active connection.

Comment: @sandeep_jagtap yes, all this has been in Android since API level 1

Comment: `getActiveNetworkInfo()` will return null if the phone is in flight mode, even though 'mobile data' setting is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE FOR ANDROID 5.0+ (API 21+)**

Calling `getMobileDataEnabled` via the reflection leads to `NoSuchMethodException` on Android 5.0+ on some devices. So in **addition** to accepted answer you may wanna do second check if `NoSuchMethodException` is thrown.

```
...
catch(NoSuchMethodException e)
{
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  {
      isDataEnabled = Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "mobile_data", 0) == 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any such constant "mobile_data" under in Settings.Global https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html I wonder how is it working or you.

Comment: @LoveForDroid the "@Hide" annotation.

Comment: does this code work for os 7+? And can u provice code for OS < 5

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code this is working for all API versions:

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                          activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

if(isConnected)
{
if(activeNetwork.getType()==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
return true;    

else
    return false;
}

else
    return false;
```

Comment: This will tell me about my active network. I want to know if mobile network is turned of by the user. If I'm connected to wifi the answer could still be both yes and no.

Comment: this only get active network, if user enable both wifi and 3b, then always return TYPE_WIFI if connected by wifi

Answer (score 0):

```
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    boolean hasTelephony = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation of what exactly does your code do?

Comment: see here to understand: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html