# Check programmatically if mobile data switch is on or off (don't want checking data connection)

Tags: android, connection, toggle, android-switch, mobile-data

How to check programmatically if mobile data switch is on or off.

I know how to check if data connection is on or not. But I don't want that.

I want to check if user have switch on that toggle switch or check box to start data connection.

Is there any event or broadcast after user toggles that switch in Settings

Because it takes 5-10 seconds to actually start data connection after enabling that switch or check-box.

Comment: Pre-5.0 you could use reflection and an undocumented API to do this, but on 5.0 it doesn't work anymore.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224097/how-to-check-if-mobile-network-is-enabled-disabled

Comment: i tried that reflection solution on 4.4.2 samsung tab, it wasn't working. by d ve, thanks